# Best practice for popup if whole message can't fit in window

Tags: popup

I recently added a popup to my app/website warning users of a coming maintenance window.  On phones, it appeared as a little window, slightly smaller than the webpage beneath it. The popup had an "OK" button at the bottom to close the window.

The complete message and button would normally show, but, in some cases, people had set their device font so large that the button was pushed down and didn't appear. The popup allowed scrolling, but some people weren't aware that you could scroll in it. They read the message and then didn't know what to do. They were stuck.

How do I avoid this? Should a popup always be closeable from a top X? I would like for people to read the message. Or is there a good way to indicate scrolling on a mobile device? Or maybe popups on phones should always be full-page instead of little windows on top of a page since people know to scroll on pages?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a 'Load more' button like editorial sites use to expand the article. By being specific about the fact that the full message is not being viewed, you are showing them directly.

If it's absolutely required to view the full message before hitting OK, you could disable the button and make them view.

Not all pop ups have a closeable X. Some products have removed this to ensure the user is reading the action buttons.

[image]

Comment: In your picture, it looks like the OK button is always viewable, and you scroll the window above it. Would you say that either way is good?

Comment: My thought is that the button is always visible, but you could disable it so that the user first has to engage the full message in some way (if it's that crucial for them to pay attention to). But either way, the 'Read more' is a more obvious way to direct their attention to the message.